# Can't authenticate when using download_data on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

trying to download all my app data using appcfg.py download_data as follows:

```
(venv)awp$ ../google_appengine/appcfg.py download_data --application=s~app-name --url=http://app-name.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=dev-datastore/data.csv
```

I have included in app.yaml:

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

also tried using service account credentials, but got the same exception, I have triple checked my email and password are correct and the app-name. I have granted myself all possible permissions in IAM pane on cloud dashboard, but still no love...

```
(venv)awp$ GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=../app-name-51362728f4a9.json ../google_appengine/appcfg.py download_data --authenticate_service_account --application=s~app-name --url=http://app-name.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=dev-datastore/data.csv --noisy
04:46 PM Downloading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20161206.164650
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20161206.164650.sql3
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-results-20161206.164650.sql3
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-0] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-1] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-2] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-3] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-4] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-5] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-6] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-7] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-8] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] [WorkerThread-9] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG   ] Configuring remote_api. url_path = /_ah/remote_api, servername = app-name.appspot.com
[DEBUG   ] Bulkloader using app_id: s~app-name
[INFO    ] Connecting to app-name.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
Please enter login credentials for app-name.appspot.com
Email: anthony@app-name.com
Password for anthony@app-name.com: 
[ERROR   ] Exception during authentication
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ant/Documents/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 3466, in Run
    self.request_manager.Authenticate()
  File "/Users/Ant/Documents/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1329, in Authenticate
    remote_api_stub.MaybeInvokeAuthentication()
  File "/Users/Ant/Documents/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 889, in MaybeInvokeAuthentication
    datastore_stub._server.Send(datastore_stub._path, payload=None)
  File "/Users/Ant/Documents/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 441, in Send
    self._Authenticate()
  File "/Users/Ant/Documents/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 582, in _Authenticate
    super(HttpRpcServer, self)._Authenticate()
  File "/Users/Ant/Documents/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 313, in _Authenticate
    auth_token = self._GetAuthToken(credentials[0], credentials[1])
  File "/Users/Ant/Documents/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 252, in _GetAuthToken
    response = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
[ERROR   ] Authentication Failed: Incorrect credentials or unsupported authentication type (e.g. OpenId).
```

any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting the credentials to your credentials file.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./app-name-51362728f4a9.json
```

Comment: How I run this command? In local Gcloud console? It does not work?